# Use the "ovs-vsctl show" command can not find OVS bridge that created by OVSDB

Tags: opendaylight, openvswitch

I use the OVSDB Southbound Plugin RESTAPI to create bridge as follow:

```
HTTP PUT:http://<controller-ip>:8181/restconf/config/networktopology:network-topology/topology/ovsdb:1/node/ofconfig％2Fbridge％2Fbrtest
Body:{"network-topology:node": [
{
  "node-id": "ofconfig％2Fbridge％2Fbrtest",
  "ovsdb:bridge-name": "brtest",
  "ovsdb:protocol-entry": [
    {
      "protocol": "ovsdb:ovsdb-bridge-protocol-openflow-13"
    }
  ],
  "ovsdb:managed-by": "/network-topology:network-topology/network-topology:topology[network-topology:topology-id='ovsdb:1']/network-topology:node[network-topology:node-id='ofconfig']"
}]}
```

And the result is 201 Created.But when i use the "ovs-vsctl show" command in OVS host,i can not find the "brtest" bridge. So, anyone can help me to solve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

is your ovs connected? even without a switch being connected, it's still possible
to create a bridge in the config store.

do a GET on the topology from the operational store and see if you have the right
node id, etc. the URI should be:

```
/restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology/topology/ovsdb:1
```

just seeing ovsdb:1 is not indicative of your ovs being connected. That just
means that you are actually running the ovsdb southbound in odl.

example of my setup with ovsdb installed and no ovs connected:

```
# curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:8181/restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology/topology/ovsdb:1 | python -m json.tool 

{
    "topology": [
        {
            "topology-id": "ovsdb:1"
        }
    ]
}
```

now, connecting my ovs:

```
# ovs-vsctl set-manager tcp:127.0.0.1:6640
# ovs-vsctl show | egrep connec
        is_connected: true
# ovs-vsctl show
28bde339-8db8-4848-a1fc-4a9ecc81b5c3
    Manager "tcp:127.0.0.1:6640"
        is_connected: true
    ovs_version: "2.9.0"
[root@jamo-rc701 karaf-0.9.0-SNAPSHOT]# curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:8181/restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology/topology/ovsdb:1 | python -m json.tool 

{
    "topology": [
        {
            "node": [
                {
                    "node-id": "ovsdb://uuid/28bde339-8db8-4848-a1fc-4a9ecc81b5c3",
                    "ovsdb:connection-info": {
                        "local-ip": "127.0.0.1",
                        "local-port": 6640,
                        "remote-ip": "127.0.0.1",
                        "remote-port": 60478
                    },
                    "ovsdb:datapath-type-entry": [
                        {
                            "datapath-type": "ovsdb:datapath-type-netdev"
                        },
                        {
                            "datapath-type": "ovsdb:datapath-type-system"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ovsdb:db-version": "7.15.1",
                    "ovsdb:interface-type-entry": [
                        {
                            "interface-type": "ovsdb:interface-type-lisp"
                        },
                        {
                            "interface-type": "ovsdb:interface-type-geneve"
                        },
                        {
                            "interface-type": "ovsdb:interface-type-gre"
                        },
                        {
                            "interface-type": "ovsdb:interface-type-system"
                        },
                        {
                            "interface-type": "ovsdb:interface-type-vxlan"
                        },
                        {
                            "interface-type": "ovsdb:interface-type-internal"
                        },
                        {
                            "interface-type": "ovsdb:interface-type-stt"
                        },
                        {
                            "interface-type": "ovsdb:interface-type-tap"
                        },
                        {
                            "interface-type": "ovsdb:interface-type-patch"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ovsdb:manager-entry": [
                        {
                            "connected": true,
                            "number_of_connections": 1,
                            "target": "tcp:127.0.0.1:6640"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ovsdb:openvswitch-external-ids": [
                        {
                            "external-id-key": "hostname",
                            "external-id-value": "localhost"
                        },
                        {
                            "external-id-key": "system-id",
                            "external-id-value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "external-id-key": "rundir",
                            "external-id-value": "/var/run/openvswitch"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ovsdb:ovs-version": "2.9.0"
                }
            ],
            "topology-id": "ovsdb:1"
        }
    ]
}
```

notice that ovs-vsctl show says is_connected: true, and also take note of
the actual node-id

Comment: Yes, I am sure my ovs connected. Because when I install odl-ovsdb-southbound-impl-ui in Karaf, then I do GET on the topology i can see "ovsdb:1" of the "topology-id ".